# Adding <label> with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I would like to add the following tag:

```
<label class="indented-checkbox-text" for="cb1">Add to favorites</label>
```

after

```
<input id="cb1" type="checkbox"/>
```

if input is bs4.element.Tag,

```
    label = soup2.new_tag('label')
    label['for'] = "cb1"
    label['class'] = "indented-checkbox-text"
    input.insert_after(label)
```

How do I add "Add to favorites" as text?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.append()` function:

```py
label = soup2.new_tag('label')
label['for'] = "cb1"
label['class'] = "indented-checkbox-text"

label.append("Add to favorites")

input.insert_after(label)
```

Source: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring-and-new-tag

Answer (score 1):

You can add whole `BeautifulSoup()` after a `Tag`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<input id="cb1" type="checkbox"/>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
inp = soup.select_one("#cb1")

inp.insert_after(
    BeautifulSoup(
        '\n<label class="indented-checkbox-text" for="cb1">Add to favorites</label>',
        "html.parser",
    )
)

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```html
<input id="cb1" type="checkbox"/>
<label class="indented-checkbox-text" for="cb1">Add to favorites</label>
```